# returning undefined JSON on weather API

Tags: json, api, google-sheets, weather

I am trying to create a google sheet that will fetch live data from openweather.org , I have managed to fetch live min and max temp, however everytime I am trying to access the ["weather"]["main"] it's returning "undefined" can please someone help me? what am I doing wrong?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
resJson.weather[0].main
```

or

```
resJson['weather'][0]['main']
```

Comment: Thank you very much! would you be able to explain this? im only starting to familiarise myself with it

Comment: `weather` is an array because there are brackets like these `"weather":[___]`, and here we just fetch the first element [0] and then we can add the subelement you need as 'main'